# Regarding PMD Rules in SOQL

Tags: salesforce, apex, pmd

I am facing below PMD error :
"Query parameters should be validated so queries are not performed if their parameters are empty"
I tried below approach but the issue is still not resolved.Kindly suggest, if any other approach can help to solve the issue.
example:
if(isNotBlank(accName)){
for(account a:[select id Name from Name=:accName]{

}
}

Comment: That's not valid syntax, you sure it saved OK? `SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :accName]`. If it didn't compile ok it'd explain why the warning still shows up. What exactly do you use? VSCode apex-pmd plugin? https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex.html? clayton? something else?

Comment: @eyescream.Sorry it's typo mistake.I am using  pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex.html

Comment: I don't see that rule on the list, maybe something custom your colleagues added on top of standard ruleset. You'd have to poke whoever made the rule. In this particular one I think you're good because Account.Name can never be empty, the if's idea looks ok (apart from syntax errors)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will check on the ruleset